# Леночка Ивановна, предложите гостю чаю

Tags: терминология, разговорная-речь

Вопрос с подвопросами о речи с сюсюканьем, нежничанием...

Есть ли (возможна ли) такая форма обращения по мужескому адресу? Как правильно назвать, квалифицировать такое распространённое явление?

(Фрагмент полностью: *«Потом будете говорить, какие мы такие-сякие хозяева. Леночка Ивановна, предложите гостю чаю. Высокий старческий голос ее источал иезуитскую нежность, от улыбки лицо совсем сморщилось, превратилось в скукоженный, трухлявый гриб.»* В. Валеева. Скорая помощь (2002).

Comment: «андрюша николаевич»? Примерно как Гоша Куценко — просто неполное имя, не чистый случай сюсюканья.

Comment: Я бы назвал такое явление лингвистической деградацией.

Comment: Слышал о синониме «сюсю» — и это чуть крепче — разврат.

Comment: @shampar (Почему-то не получил сигнала о Вашем ответе на мой комментарий — поэтому не заметил.)  [Вот другой пример](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1047&bih=480&tbm=bks&ei=ycflWqipEcbfwAL79qNI&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%22&oq=%22%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5874.14242.0.14448.23.22.1.0.0.0.264.2910.0j15j3.18.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.1.140...0.0.3fOoY4VXGHk).

Comment: Благодарю за труд. Да, ничего невозможного нет.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли (возможна ли) такая форма обращения по мужескому адресу?

Рискую обидеть феминисток, но подобное сюсюканье (или, если хотите, нежное обращение), простительное по отношению к слабому полу, кажется мне совершенно неуместным по отношению к мужчинам.